# How protect web-application against user session hijacking?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, session

I need to protect my web-application(C#,MVC) against user session hijacking.  This web-application using a lot of AJAX components.

Some edits:
I mean protection against interception of session identifiers. i have specific architecture in my project: autorization point on C# and external server that returns me session id. This session id is used in javascript components on client side. I want to protect that session id against substitution.

Is https the only way to do this? And if use https will it protect me against intercepting the session id?

Comment: Why do you insist on not using https? It's the only proper way of doing this.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is way too broad. Please narrow down the scope of your question. Are you talking protection about cookie strings? Sniffing traffic? etc?

Comment: You can't really. You can only make it harder and/or reduce the time window in which an attacker has to execute.

Comment: I mean protection against interception of session identifiers. i have specific architecture in my project: autoriztion point on C# and external server that returns me session id. This session id using into javascript components on client side. I want to potect that session id aginst substitution.

Comment: encrypting it from server side doesn't solve the issue?

Comment: Those session identifiers are going to be sent over the internet in plain text. The only way to protect against this is using asymmetric encryption (assuming you can't pre-share a secure key with your users). The simplest implementation of asymmetric key encryption over HTTP to implement would be HTTPS. However you could in theory try to implement a secure asymmetric key algorithm in javascript!

Comment: WAIT...you don't mean to say you want to stop the user from CHANGING the session key in his client? If that is the case, you have a 'Trusted Platform' problem. In other words you can't, without PHYSICALLY locking the user's machine (and even then you can't be sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should read the session management cheat sheet of OWAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Second: SSL prevents from some specific attacks, so you need it in order secure your session id, but it is not the only thing you have to consider

Third: It's not that good idea to make your Session ID accessible via JavaScript, because it can be stolen if there are vulnerabilities like Cross-Site Scripting.

Is it really necessary to have this session id available with JavaScript? It would be a good idea, to set it as a cookie, set the HttpOnly (No JS-Access) and Secure-Flag (Only transferred over HTTPS) flags and let the browser transparently do the session handling, as the cookies is transferred with every request.